# How to iterate through tuple and plot values in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have processed a JSON via web request and am trying to iterate through the device elements to plot via matplotlib, however have been struggling to correctly address each index element.

I am receiving the JSON like this:

```
key_list = ['RSSI', 'charge (mV)'] 
key_str = ','.join(key_list)

teledata = dict()
for device, id in devices.items():
    response = requests.get(f'https://apiurl/')
    returned_data = json.loads(response.text.encode().decode('utf-8-sig'))
    teledata[device] = returned_data
```

`teledata` is then converted into a tuple with: `teledata.items()` which you will see in the code below, and when I print `teledata.list()` it returns the following:

```
{
    "DeviceA": {
        "success": true,
        "message": "",
        "data": [
        {
         "RSSI":"-77",
         "charge (mV)":"215.824"
        },
        {
         "RSSI":"-79",
         "charge (mV)":"215.875"
        }
        ]
    },
    "DeviceB": {
        "success": true,
        "message": "",
        "data": [
        {
         "RSSI":"-72",
         "charge (mV)":"210.824"
        },
        {
         "RSSI":"-73",
         "charge (mV)":"210.875"
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

What I am essentially trying to do is plot on one graph the values for RSSI and charge for both devices on two seperate plots with the following section:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(key_list))
fig.suptitle('Data')

for i, key in enumerate(key_list):
    for device, data in teledata.items():
        timeseries = list()
        values = list()
        try:
            for datapoint in data[key]:
                timeseries.append(float(datapoint['RSSI']))
                values.append(float(datapoint['charge']))
        except KeyError:
            print(f"No data for {key} in device {device}")
        axs[i].plot(timeseries, values)
        axs[i].set_title(key)
        axs[i].set_ylim([0, 100])
plt.show()
```

However I keep hitting my exception block saying there is not data, but when I check my variables in the watcher window while debugging, I can see that the values are present within the `data` variable. I thought maybe it was an indexing problem, so started by commenting out the plotting and just trying to print `data[0][key]`, but received the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: KeyError
0
```

Comment: Where do the `ts` and `value` keys come from? It's not in your `teledata` dictionary. To access the "data[0][key]", you need to print it as:
`print(data["data"][0][key])`

Comment: @kamion sorry - old values. I've updated the post. Should be `RSSI` and `charge`.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop over `teledata.items()`, `data` is the following (first iteration):

```
{
        "success": true,
        "message": "",
        "data": [
        {
         "RSSI":"-77",
         "charge (mV)":"215.824"
        },
        {
         "RSSI":"-79",
         "charge (mV)":"215.875"
        }
        ]
    }
```

There is no `0` key in this dictionary. You probably meant to access the first element of the list under `"data"`, which can be accessed with:

```
data["data"][0]
```